# How many hp Li Li's "Jug of 1,000,000 Cups" can potentially heal

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

So, on level 20 Li Li's heroic ability "Jug of 1,000 Cups":

> Rapidly tosses brew to the most injured nearby allies, prioritizing Heroes, restoring a total of 3600 Health over 6 seconds.

... and can be upgraded to "Jug of 1,000,000 Cups":

> Jug of 1,000 Cups now hits two targets at a time.

I can interpret this as one of:

1. a total amount of hp Li Li can restore now equals to 7200 (assuming there are 2 or more heroes being healed)
2. a total amount of hp being restored is still 3600, but now it can heal up to 2 times faster, i.e. 3 seconds (assuming there are 2 or more heroes being healed)

Which one is really happening here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is the first one.

> a total amount of hp Li Li can restore now equals to 7200 (assuming there are 2 or more heroes being healed)

On 2nd screenshot, I took the talent and then used the ultimate. You can see both Malfurion and Li Li is healed by 150 per jug.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, Li Li's ult potentially heals 3600 health over time, doesn't matter which hero... Throwing 2 cups at the same time means you can potentially heal 2 heroes (or more) for potentially 3600 health for each cup.

So basically, you can say you heal a potential amount of 7200.